# How to save a textbox value into a folder as .txt and get the time stamp as filename using VB?

Tags: vb.net, timestamp, save, directory

Here is my code:

```
Private CurrentRecipient As String
Private User As String = "Name"
Dim UserFolder As String
Dim FileName As String = Format(Now, "MMMMDDDDYYYYHHNNSS") & ".txt"

Private Sub SendButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    SendButton.Click
    If CurrentRecipient = "Edward" Then
        UserFolder = "C:\Users\bele\Desktop\Edward'sFolder" & FileName
    ElseIf CurrentRecipient = "Criziel" Then
        UserFolder = "C:\Users\bele\Desktop\Criziel'sFolder" & FileName

    End If
```

' I received no error but once I have send a message It does not doe anything :(

Comment: What were you expecting this code to do?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am asked to enter a text to a textbox then this text should be automatically saved to a folder . and then the file name must be the timestamp. Any suggestion ?

Comment: You seem to be missing any code that would take the text from the TextBox and write it to the file. You might want to look at the documentation for [File.WriteAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I have added :

    Dim Writer As New IO.StreamWriter(RecipientFolder & FileName)
        Writer.Write(ShowtextRichTextBox.Text)  to my code . I can now save the txt file with time stamp but the txt that I have entered still do not appear :(

Comment: Please bear with me. I am a newbie :(

Comment: Please edit your question to show the actual code you are using now and describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add the following Imports above your Form Class.

Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

You will need to add a TextBox control named txtFolderName to enter the folder names (Edward's or Criziel)for this to work. Enter the name of the folder on the Desktop (Edward's or Criziel) into txtFolderName, Click the button named Button1 and it will create the file inside the correct folder.

I'm guessing this is just testing code ideas, because you should also make the Directory Path a variable that you can enter in a TextBox

```
 Private Sub SaveFile()

    Dim UserFolder As String = ""
    Dim FileName As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyHHmmss") & ".txt"
    Dim fs As FileStream

    UserFolder = "C:\Users\bele\Desktop\" & txtFolderName.Text & "\" & FileName

    ' Create a file
    fs = File.Create(UserFolder)

End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SaveFile()

End Sub
```

Good Luck!

Comment out the fs = File.Create(UserFolder) line and add this code just below it.

```
    Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(UserFolder)
        sw.WriteLine("Hello")
        sw.WriteLine("And")
        sw.WriteLine("Welcome")
    End Using
```

Comment: Hi rob b. Thank you ! :)